# Windows 7 64 bit with CURL Fatal error: Call to undefined function curl_init()

Tags: php, windows, curl

I need to make work CURL IN WAMP

Running cmd.exe, I am able to use curl

```
 curl -L http://www.google.com
```

But when using my website locally  (using WAMP, PHP Version 5.3.13) even with enabling extension for `curl`.

I get an error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function curl_init()
```

My PC is a Windows 7 64 bit..Any ideas on how to solve it?

Comment: What does your phpInfo() say? Is there a section with heading curl? You need to have cURL support enabled in PHP.

Comment: Are you sure you have enabled `curl` & restart your Apache ?

Comment: section with heading curl is not present when I do phpinfo(). In Wamp under PHP and php.ini extension=php_curl.dll is un commented ... any idea?

Comment: yes apache restarted and wamp services restarted... same problem

Comment: yes I have restarted wamp... SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for and Fatal error: Call to undefined function curl_init() i

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem installing WAMP 32 bit version on WIN 7 64BIT, in this way CURL worked.

Answer (score 2):

Go to [www.anindya.com](http://www.anindya.com) download *php_curl-5.4.3-VC9-x64.zip* under "Fixed curl extensions:" and replace the php_curl.dll in ext folder.

via. http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,85642

Comment: This approach worked checking with CMD, but no in WWW folder for WAMP